How can I retain only the lines in code fences?
I am trying to modify a text file and am wondering if Vim is a suitable tool for the job. If it is how I could use Vim to do it?
A simplified version of the file (which is actually at gedcom-3-structures-1-organization.md) is shown below:
line 1 is irrelevant
followed by many irrelevant lines
```gedstruct
line I do want
line I do want
```
another line I do not want
and more I don`t want
```gedstruct
line I do want
line I do want
```
more lines I don`t want

So I want to retain the lines between these two lines:
```gedstruct

and
```

I have spent some time trying to write a bash script using tools such as sed, awk and grep to do this but I feel I would much rather concentrate my efforts learning Vim which I can already use to some extent as I am getting very out of my depth with this whole project.
Obviously, if Vim is a bad choice of tool for doing this I will have to think again.

I took the liberty to change your question's title. I felt that it was too general. Feel free to improve further.

I would do:
%s/\_.\{-}```.*\n\(\_.\{-}\)```\(\_.\{-}\ze\(\%$\|```\)\)\?/\1/

Or:
%s/\v\_.{-}```.*\n(\_.{-})```(\_.{-}\ze(%$|```))?/\1/

Explanation

\v turns very magic mode on
\_.{-}``` match any string (including carriage return (\_.) till the first ``` (because of the non greedy quantifier {-})
.*\n match till the end of the line (the gedstruct part)
(\_.{-})```  grab the lines till the first ``` not included (because of the non greedy quantifier {-})
(\_.{-}\ze(%$|```))? match before (\ze) either to the next ``` occurence or to the end of the end of the file (%$)


Another technique is to use the tools you do know; in this case, a simple Awk program extracts the relevant lines:
:%!awk '/```$/ { keep = 0; } keep; /```gedstruct/ { keep = 1; }'

(the order of the commands is important to not print the gedstruct lines).
Small Awk primer
Awk is quite effective for building small state-machines. Once you've seen this pattern it becomes easier to apply elsewhere. Typical programs have:

state variable(s), in this case keep;
actions that manipulate the state (transitions); and
actions that use the state to make decisions.

Note that unset variables default to 0, which is convenient for scripting.
See your local Awk manual or the POSIX spec (Shell & Utilities > Utilities > awk) for more details.
Program explanation
The program uses keep as a state variable to control when to print lines: if it is truthy (non-zero), lines are printed. If it is falsey (zero), lines are skipped. We use the fact that an empty action means { print; } (much like the Awk idiom 1; to print all lines): Boolean expressions can be used as patterns in Awk.
As state transitions: When we see a closing block /```$/, we transition to stop printing lines by setting keep = 0. When we see an opening block ```gedstruct, we transition to start printing future lines by setting keep = 1. The decision to print has already been processed, so we won't print the gedstruct line (add an explicit print; to that action or move it before keep; to print those lines, too).
Variants
This program prints the headers and footers, and is similar to an ed/sed/Vim range:
:%!awk '/```gedstruct/,/```$/'

Once again we use the "empty action means print; means print $0; idiom.
To exclude the the header/footer in this version, we can add a test in the action:
:%!awk '/```gedstruct/,/```$/ { if (!/^```/) print; }'


could you explain that a little please. I know that awk looks line by line and if it evaluates an expression using the line as input to 0 (or other false value) it does not print the line but it it evaluates to a true value it prints. I can not quite see how that applies here. I imagine keep is a variable and some lines will give it value 0 and others value 1.

@user3425506 added! Awk can do a great many things; I think the key to understanding many Awk programs that are more advanced that /pat/ { print $subfield …; } is state-machine thinking.

As an aside, it may be worth mentioning the much simpler awk program /^```gedstruct$/,/^```$/ (yes, that's the complete program), which does exactly what OP wants except that it outputs the matched lines as well as what's between them.  You could expand it to e.g. /^```gedstruct$/,/^```$/ { if (!/^```/) print } to exclude the matched lines, but that's a bit ugly.

@gidds nice, will include.

This is one of the cases where I'd prefer a recursive macro over the :substitute command.
Substitution works best line-wise.
In this case, only a few very basic commands are needed.
You can record the keys while you edit and replay them later.
I already mentioned I would record a recursive macro, that's why we need to clear the register first.
Let's say we want to use the a register, typing qaq will record a zero-length macro and thus clear it.
Let's start with the actual recording.
Go to the top of your file and type the command below
qad/^```<CR>ddn@aq
qa                 - record a macro into register 'a'
  d/^```<CR>       - delete to a line that starts with three backticks. <CR> is the enter key
            dd     - delete the current line (with three backticks) as well
              n    - go to the next line with three backticks, this skips over the text we want to keep
               @a  - call the macro in register 'a' (currently empty)
                 q - finish recording the 'a' macro

By now, the text before the first code block should have been deleted.
You can hit @a to run the macro until the last line with three backticks.
This is because we have a @a inside our recording.
When we run it now, a will no longer be empty.
The macro calls itself recursively.
There's a minor caveat: this macro will not delete the text after the last code block.
Just throw it out with a dG and we're done.
Macros are explained in :help complex-repeat.
But is it the right tool for the job?
Concerning your question:

I [...] am wondering if Vim is a suitable tool for the job?

Yes it is, in general, as evidenced by the answers.
However, it's certainly not the only tool for the job.
The question whether Vim is suitable for you is one only you can answer yourself.
There are many text editors out there with different features.
Using Vim won't magically turn you into a hacker.
It's not a silver bullet.
Vim is famous for its learning curve (I'm avoiding the words "steep" and "shallow" because people don't get how learning curves work).
You can get up to speed by running vimtutor and reading :help user-manual.
